# Solve nonlinear system with eight variables

Tags: equation-solving

Please I realy need Help
We consider the three functions
H1=4(x+b1 y)^2+8(c1x-d1 y)+e1^2 y^2,  with  e1>0
H2=4(x+b2 y)^2+8(c2 x-d2 y)+e2^2 y^2,  with e2>0
H3=4(x+b3 y)^2+8(c3 x-d3 y)+e3^2 y^2,  with e3>0...d1,b1,c1,d2,c2,b2, d3,c3,b3 are real parameters.
I would like to solve (to get the values of alpha, beta, gamma, delta, f,h,g,k) the following system or (if it is not possible) to give the  maximal number of its solutions
The system is E1=E2=E3=E4=E5=E6=E7=E8=0 such that 
E1=H1(alpha,beta)-H1(gamma,delta) , E2=H2(alpha,beta)-H2(f,g), E3=H2(gamma,delta)-H2(h,k), E4=H3(h,k)-H3(f,g), E5=beta^2-alpha(alpha-1)(alpha-3), E6=delta^2-gamma(gamma-1)(gamma-3), E7=g^2-f(f-1)(f-3), E8=k^2-h(h-1)(h-3).

Comment: Please provide at least valid _Mathematica_ code for the equations and example values for the parameters. Having to guess the parameter ranges for which you need solutions is quite a pain.

Comment: Probably not feasible to get an analytic solution. For specified numeric values of the parameters it might be possible to get solutions using `NSolve` and also `FindRoot` should work for getting a single solution. As for counting them, if the need is to get a max count on real solutions subject to the parameter constraints, again that will not be feasible. Counting complex-valued solutions is a different matter-- just plug in random values for the parameters and if `NSolve` handles that, you have your result.

Comment: Thank you sir for your attention of my question

Comment: If you give the context for this problem, there may be other,  more geometric methods to find solutions.

Comment: What do you mean by context?

Answer (score 4):

Translating your question to *Mathematica* to get you started:

```
H1[x_, y_] = 4 (x + b1 y)^2 + 8 (c1 x - d1 y) + e1^2 y^2;
H2[x_, y_] = 4 (x + b2 y)^2 + 8 (c2 x - d2 y) + e2^2 y^2;
H3[x_, y_] = 4 (x + b3 y)^2 + 8 (c3 x - d3 y) + e3^2 y^2;

E1 = H1[α, β] - H1[γ, δ];
E2 = H2[α, β] - H2[f, g];
E3 = H2[γ, δ] - H2[h, k];
E4 = H3[h, k] - H3[f, g];
E5 = β^2 - α (α - 1) (α - 3);
E6 = δ^2 - γ (γ - 1) (γ - 3);
E7 = g^2 - f (f - 1) (f - 3);
E8 = k^2 - h (h - 1) (h - 3);

Assuming[Element[{d1, b1, c1, d2, c2, b2, d3, c3, b3}, Reals] && 
  e1 > 0 && e2 > 0 && e3 > 0, 
  Solve[E1 == E2 == E3 == E4 == E5 == E6 == E7 == E8 == 0,
    {α, β, γ, δ, f, h, g, k}]]
```

Comment: I did it but it is not easy and mathematica did not give ,e a result